# Find a dynamic <input> tag with Capybara/Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, google-chrome-headless

I have the following HTML:

```
<label for="file-input-76eb2" id="ember3042" class="c-text-input c-text-input o-grid-cell--6 file-upload ember-view">
  <input id="file-input-76eb2" type="file" accept="text/csv" style="display: none;">
  <span class="c-file-upload__input-filename"></span>
  <a class="c-button c-button--single-action-primary c-file-upload__input-button">
      Select
  </a>
</label>
```

I have managed to get a Capybara::Node:Element corresponding to the label tag, but I can't get to the input. The id is dynamic- constantly changing. Moreover, I need to upload a file to this input tag.

Is there any information what I can do? This is all using google-chrome-headless.

This is using Ruby, with Capybara, with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

label_element.find(:xpath, '//input') did it!